# List command is not loading source code of assembly program in gdb

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

I am using gdb [7.11.1] kali linux 32-bit
when I use list command to lload the source of my assembly program in gdb it displays the following error message:
'No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command'

I have tried the command as:

list
list line_number

In both the cases the error is same.

Please help me

Thanks! in advance

Comment: How did you assembly your assembly program? What commands did you type with what flags? Please also post the output of running `nm` on your program.

Comment: a simple program for moving data in registers to memory and vice versa

Comment: Please answer my questions; depending on how you assembled and linked your program, you might have stripped it, removing the symbol table (note how gdb complains about a lacking symbol table).

Comment: as -o progname.o progname.s

Comment: ld -o progname progname.o

Comment: In this case, there should be a symbol table. Can you post your assembly as well as the output of `nm progname`?

Answer (score 2):

> I use list command to lload the source of my assembly

List command does *nothing* of the sort. Rather, it lists sources that GDB has already loaded.

> `as -o progname.o progname.s`

In your case, GDB does not load any sources because you compiled your program without any debug info. You likely want:

```
as -g -o progname.o progname.s
```

From [man as](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/as.1.html):

```
  -g
   --gen-debug
       Generate debugging information for each assembler source line
       using whichever debug format is preferred by the target.  This
       currently means either STABS, ECOFF or DWARF2.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was incurring same problem while I was trying to debug my c code for buffer overflow stuffs.
That error rises because of clean compiling without generating any debug info.
For c program, rather than normal compiling as `gcc program.c` try to run `gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -z exec stack -o buffer program.c`. 
`-g` tells GCC to add extra information for GDB
`-fno-stack-protector` flag to turn off stack protection mechanism
`-z execstack`, it makes stack executable
This command will create a `buffer` binary file of your c program and hence it will fulfil all the criteria for running the list command in gdb.

Start the gdb with `gdb ./buffer` then type `list` command. It will work!!